# Android layout: make it look like in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I have here 2 images the one is from the android studio while the other one is from the emulator, The problem is that the two images don't look like each other I mean this is probably because of the different screen sizes but they just differ to much. How can I make it look like in the android studio version?

Android Studio

[image: Android Studio]

Emulator

[image: emulator]

Comment: Change the preview device in Android Studio to the correct dimensions

Comment: cricket_007 comment is the correct answer.

Comment: Your actual device has a different pixel density then your preview device. That's why you are seeing different results.

Answer (score 2):

You should choose a preview device with a smaller screen: your layout doesn't scale appropriately, so you can see artifacts depending on the device screen resolution and size.

Comment: true. higher density and small screen size emulater will solve this problem.